# How to retrieve data from an Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

When I run the following code I receive the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Can anyone suggest why that might be?

```
namespace ATMPROJECT
{
    public partial class pin : Form
    {
        public pin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection ();
            OleDbCommand cmd;

            DataSet ds;
            OleDbDataAdapter da;
            OleDbDataReader dr = null;
            string i;
             con = new OleDbConnection ( "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\\Users\\RELIABLE TRADING CO\\Documents\\atm.accdb ");
            con.Open();
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                label1.Text  = ("PLZ ENTER YOUR PIN FIRST");

            }
            else
            {

                ds = new DataSet();

                i = @"SELECT * from atm WHERE pin= ?";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(i,con);


                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@pin",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1 .Text;
                 da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);


                 MessageBox.Show("done");
                 da.Fill(ds);
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

// generates error (No value given for one or more required parameters.)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates your `atm` table does not have a field called `pin`.

Also, you probably have to specify the table in the DataSource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```